# BIML creating bad metadata

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, biml

I have a project moving data from a MySQL database to a DB in SQL2012.  Right now there's nothing fancy, just a straight push of data.  I'm access the MySQL instance via ODBC and the SQL DB is an OLE connection. When the packages are generated there is a metadata mismatch between the ODBC source and the OLE destination.  (that's all there is to the data flow so far)  The message states "Column "" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string types."

Examining the metadata in the path editor between the source & destination shows that the problem source columns are being read as DT_STR with a length of 255 and code page of 1252.  In MySQL however they are collated as utf8_general_ci which is unicode.

The corresponding columns in the target SQL database tables are varchar of the same length.

If I open up the OLE destination and click OK the metadata refreshes and it works fine after saving the package.  That defeats the whole purpose of using BIML to create the packages and takes forever to go open up 50+ packages to refresh the metadata and save.

I have tried several things with no changes in behavior:

- Changing between the unicode and ansi MySQL odbc drivers.
- Tried making the destination columns nvarchar.  But I had to put in data conversion transforms to make that work.
- Surrounded the schema/table names in [] in the ExternalTableOutput element of the OLEDBDestination.
- Changed SQL Native Client Versions.
- Put a 'COLLATE latin1_bin' statement at the end of the source queries pulling from MySQL.
- Originally was in VS2015 w/ BimlExpress and tried it in SSDT 2012 w/ BimlExpress. (btw...had to install SSDT for 2014 in order to get BIML to compile in SSDT2012 because of missing Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Interfaces dll)

Any ideas would be welcome, I'm pretty much at the end of my imagination on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a different connection type, such as `ADO`?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar problem.  In the end I had to open the generated packaged in notepad and replaced the word bytes with wstr through the text file.   I saved and reopened and it all works.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf This actually does also attempt to provide an answer.